# How to develop CMIS-WIndows explorer integration?

Tags: windows, explorer, cmis

Like WevDAV or CIFS, anyone could tell me how to develop CMIS-WIndows explorer integration? 
(I'm not intended to an independent application for CMIS browsing)

I'm familiar with developing in CMIS but have no experiece in Windows development.

Any keyword, API etc. is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks you describe Windows namespace extensions. Some links:

[Creating Shell Data Source Objects and Extending the Shell Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521656%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Specifying a Namespace Extension's Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Namespace Extensions - Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1649/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Namespace-Ex)