# Virtual filesystem integrated with windows

Tags: filesystems, explorer

I have an application that I wrote that will let me explore/manipulate Virtual disks for a legacy computer emulator. Can someone point me in the right direction hook it into Windows Explorer, in the same way that Zip Folders are integrated (also similar is Acronis True Image backup files (.tib files).

Comment: google for namespace shell extension

Comment: I have, and found lots of information, but not clear about implementation. Also found a series of articles about .Net Shell Extensions (my application is in .NET) using .NET 4.0. Seem like what I am aiming for, but not sure which implementation I need.

Comment: There are a number of "handlers" that library supports, but which one would I need to give the same behavior as ZipFolders. For example, in Windows Explorer, if there is a zip file, when I expand the folder it is in, I see any subfolders and Zip Files in the tree. if I then click a zip file in the tree, I see the zip file's contents in the detail view. Which handler does that. The series of articles I am referring to are at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125237/how-to-develop-cmis-windows-explorer-integration/21132849#21132849

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for I don't think. Those are all well and good to attach a namespace to windows explorer, but not individual file handlers as is done with Zip Files (handled by zipfldr.dll) and Acronis True Image Backup (.tib) files, which appears handled by thishell64.dll.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: If the namespace shell extension is not enough, then the only other option is to have a virtual filesystem driver. Creating one is a sophisticated process, so we offer a widely popular Callback File System product for creating filesystems in user mode.

Comment: I've browsed much of that information, but still at a bit of a loss. Are there any samples I could follow? I get the basic idea of Namespaces and played with it a bit, but again, it doesn't follow the examples I mentioned. Ideally a "zipfolders" example would help me tremendously.

Comment: I have examples now of many types of Windows Shell Extensions, such as ContextMenus, Thumbnail Handlers, Drag and Drop Handlers, Property Sheet handlers, etc... But I've seen no examples anywhere showing how to implement the actual Windows Explorer View of the content of files.